# React not re-render items after changing state

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to learn React. This snippet of code don't render

s on click. Why? I want to render my

s.

123...

```
function MyP({index}) {
    return (
        <p>{index}</p>
    );
}

function MyApp() {
    const [n, setN] = React.useState(1);
    const [ps, setPs] = React.useState([]);



    function handleClick() {
        setN(n + 1);
        setPs([...ps, n])
        console.log(n, ps);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {ps.map((p) => {<MyP index={p}/>})}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
                Нажми меня!
            </button>
        </>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<MyApp />)
```

I tried to learn from react cite, but still have a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: you also need a `key` for `MyP`

Comment: What key? I don't understand(

Answer (score 0):

The "set state function" is an asynchronous function.  When your code first hits the call, it puts the call onto JavaScript's "asynch queue" to be executed later, then JS continues running....executing your `console.log()` before the asynchronous code gets executed.

This is the way that JavaScript works.

I strongly encourage all of my friends (and make it a requirement of all of my coworkers) to watch the video [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s) multiple times.  Especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).

Comment: But the state has been changed, when my ps will be render?

Comment: Watch the video  :) .  JS will "get around to updating the state" once it has finished off of the other priority work that is on the "main queue"....which means that React will complete rendering all of the UI it is rendering BEFORE it will update state.  Once the state is updated (by the "set state function") then the component for that state variable will be queued to re-render.

Comment: Thanx, Greg. I will watch it!